# bundle install fails because "No such file or directory"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, capistrano, bundler

I'M trying to deploy with capistrano to a staging server. This command fails both on deploy and manually:

`cd .../apps/myapp/releases/20150205154326 && ( RVM_BIN_PATH=/usr/local/rvm/bin/ PATH=/usr/bin/git:$PATH /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle install --path .../apps/myapp/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet )`

error:

`Git error: command 'git clone --no-checkout --quiet
    ".../apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/cache/bundler/git/fog-   8836460df0e4c80347618efd3adda34209f0c6f7"
   ".../apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bundler/gems/fog-   5ceace13efe1"'
in directory .../apps/myapp/releases/20150205154326 has failed.
If this error persists you could try removing the cache directory
'.../apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/cache/bundler/git/fog-8836460df0e4c80347618efd3adda34209f0c6f7'`

However, this dir exists, and the permissions are ok. I've tried to delete it and run again, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by reinstalling bundler and rvm